# View.canScrollVertically on API 11

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview

Is there a way to use something similar to "View.canScrollVertically" on API 11?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#canScrollVertically(int)

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

So, the implementation is simply:

```
public boolean canScrollVertically(int direction) {
    final int offset = computeVerticalScrollOffset();
    final int range = computeVerticalScrollRange() - computeVerticalScrollExtent();
    if (range == 0) return false;
    if (direction < 0) {
        return offset > 0;
    } else {
        return offset < range - 1;
    }
}
```

So you could easily just copy that into your code; however, the `computeX()` methods are protected. One solution here is to subclass the `View` and provide your own implementation:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public boolean compatCanScrollVertically(int direction) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            return canScrollVertically(direction);
        } else {
            // TODO Remove when minSdkVersion >= 14
            final int offset = computeVerticalScrollOffset();
            final int range = computeVerticalScrollRange() - computeVerticalScrollExtent();
            if (range == 0) return false;
            if (direction < 0) {
                return offset > 0;
            } else {
                return offset < range - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked over the SwipeRefreshLayout codes, the view has the same need for a view that whether can scroll in the specified direction.

```
/**
 * @return Whether it is possible for the child view of this layout to
 *         scroll up. Override this if the child view is a custom view.
 */
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 14) {
        if (mTarget instanceof AbsListView) {
            final AbsListView absListView = (AbsListView) mTarget;
            return absListView.getChildCount() > 0
                    && (absListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0 || absListView.getChildAt(0)
                            .getTop() < absListView.getPaddingTop());
        } else {
            return mTarget.getScrollY() > 0;
        }
    } else {
        return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(mTarget, -1);
    }
}
```

scrollDown also use same manner.

Comment: `ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(recyclerView, -1)` by itself seems like a convenient option for RecyclerView.

Comment: @android developer  It's in the v4 support library. I've tested it on v10, but it's best to refer to the docs. Remember it's just for RecyclerView though.